# Maximo Where Clause PM & JP

Tags: sql, maximo

I would appreciate some assistance on a where clause.  I am trying to establish which PMs are missing a certain JP in the sequence.  Perhaps there is a better way of doing this eg; return all PMs that don’t have JP ‘1’,‘2’,‘3’.

```
status = ‘Active’ and
siteid = ‘Earth’ and
jpnum = ‘DC 321’ and
not exists (select 1 from pmsequnce where pmsequence.jpnum = pm.pmnum and pmsequence.siteid = pm.siteid
```

I get an error and trying to establish which part I have wrong, any help would much appreciated.

Many Thanks

G

Comment: What kind of error? SQL has straight quotes, like `'Active'`.

Comment: Yip i am using straight quotes in the statement, in this example I have used what I can find on an iPad keyboard :-)

Comment: `from pmsequnce` is missing an e .. `from pmsequence`

Comment: Why are you joining PMSEQUENCE.JPNUM to PM.PMNUM? It is highly unlikely that a Job Plan number will happen to be a PM number.

Comment: Hi @Preacher, not being SQL trained I have tried to conjure this up from others that I do have working. Yes it is highly unlikely that they JP Num an PM number to be a match so the join is an error or part of the problem